# Button Clicks Triggers Storyboards

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have a Stackpanel that contains some Buttons.

(What these Buttons does, each one of them loads a Page to a Frame on Click)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Buttons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="1100" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,31,0,0">
        <Button x:Name="AjoutButton" Width="64" Content="" Style="{DynamicResource MyButton}" Click="AjoutPressed">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Backgrounds/Buttons/AjoutButton.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Left"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ConsulterButton" Width="64" Content="" Style="{DynamicResource MyButton}" Click="ConsulterPressed">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Backgrounds/Buttons/ConsultationButton.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"  AlignmentX="Left"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

And a Style for those Buttons called "MyButton".

```
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF707070"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="64" Duration="0:0:.2" To="200"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="200" Duration="0:0:.2" To="64"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>                                                   
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What this style does, it changes the button width to 200 when the mouse enters and it changes it bac to 64 when the mouse leaves.
Basically what I want to do is I want to keep the width on 200 when the button is pressed, but it's not that simple because I want aswell when another button of the same style is Pressed I want the first button to go back to normal width(64) then I want the button pressed recently to have width equals to 200.

I think I need to explain more.
For example :

(Just to clarify : the mouse enter/leave trigger works perfectly so nothing wrong with it)

Let's take AjoutButton and ConsulterButton, when I click on AjoutButton I want it width to stay at 200 (it's already 200 because the MouseOver is true), now when I Click on ConsulterButton I want it width to stay at 200 and the width of AjoutButton to go back to 64.

You might say, I can use the IsFocused Property, but it won't work perfectly because in my project I have a Frame and when I focus on the it the Button width goes back to 64.

I spent a lot of time searching a solution for this problem but nothing found..
The problem is I'm new to this so I didn't really know what to write in Google, you guys can tell even from the title of this post.